# Rotating a png image representing a unit in a game

Tags: java, graphics, png, jpanel

I am using png's in my tower defense game. How would I rotate a picture so it follows the movement of another picture (like a turret always pointing at a target)?

Comment: Too broad. How should we know what is best for your project? Best thing is if you look at similar (FLOSS) projects, learn from them and your own mistakes.

Comment: I editted the question since Bobby's post. It should be clearer now.

Comment: This is still very broad, the way to solve it depends on your design decisions so far. You would need to include some specifics about how you currently do the rotation before we could suggest improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class. The `rotate` method is what you're looking for. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/RotateImage45Degrees.htm)'s an example!

If you've got some other specific game-development-related questions, there's a [Game Development StackExchange site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) too.